# Создание директории в Entity Symfony 4

Tags: php, mvc, symfony

Изучаю Symfony, пытаюсь структурировать файлы, есть следующий класс:

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity\Admin;

class Variables
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $code;
    private $value;
    private $id_language;

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getId_language(): int
    {
        return $this->id_language;
    }

    public function getValue(): string
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

Лежит он тут:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мапинг чуть ниже. Если я переношу класс `Variables` в корневую директорию `Entity` - все работает. Когда переношу в папку `Admin` получаю следующую ошибку:

> No mapping file found named 'Variables.orm.yml' for class
>   'App\Entity\Admin\Variables'.

Что тут написано мне понятно, не понятно где он пытается искать файл маппинга, ведь по факту он существует, что нужно сделать что бы он его увидел?

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить, что у вас стандартный конфиг маппингов, возможно даже, который я вам советовал в одном из других вопросов

```
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: yml
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Mappings'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

В вашем случае, вы вынесли энтити в другой namespace, теперь, надо сконфигурировать это, чтобы доктрина понимала, что и где искать:

```
    mappings:
        User:
            is_bundle: false
            type: yml
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Mappings/User'
            prefix: 'App\Entity\User'
        Admin:
            is_bundle: false
            type: yml
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Mappings/Admin'
            prefix: 'App\Entity\Admin'
```

Обязательное условие - namespace маппинга должен совпадать с энтити